# In celery 3.1, making django periodic task

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

Things changed too much in Django, so I can't use 3.1. I need some help.

I read about [make a task in django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-first-steps), and read [Periodic Tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) document. But I don't know how make periodic tasks in django. I think this becuase of my low level English..

In the older version of Celery, I imported *djcelery*&*crontab* and set CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE in *settings.py*, and excuted by *manage.py*.

But it seems that I cannot execute celery deamon by that way anymore. Than where I should put CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE? In django example in docs, they set `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')`
 in *proj/proj/celery.py*. (1) So setting celerybeat in *settings.py*(like before) is ok?

(2) If you can, a tiny example of making periodic task in django will very helpful. When I was reading tutorials, the most confusing part was *File Path*. If you don't want to provide a whole example, I will really appreciate if you explain about where I should make tasks, set beat, and executed deamon.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I assume you've already read the [django section](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) from the docs, but have you seen this [example project](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/django)?

It doesn't use the scheduler but if you add this to `settings.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery.schedules import crontab


CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    # crontab(hour=0, minute=0, day_of_week='saturday')
    'schedule-name': {  # example: 'file-backup' 
        'task': 'some_django_app.tasks....',  # example: 'files.tasks.cleanup' 
        'schedule': crontab(...)
    },
}

# if you want to place the schedule file relative to your project or something:
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE_FILENAME = "some/path/and/filename"
```

Now for the commands, forget about `manage.py`, just type  `celery` directly:

`-B` enables celery beat as always.

`-A` specifies the name of the celery app. Note this line in the [celery.py](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/examples/django/proj/celery.py#L12) of the example project: `app = Celery('proj')`

```
celery -A proj worker -B -l info
```

'django-celery' is **not required**, install it ONLY if you need to manage 
the schedule from the admin, or if you want to store task results in the DB 
through django's ORM:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('djcelery',)

# store schedule in the DB:
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

Comment: `from celery.schedules import crontab` This line gives me the error: "No module named schedules"

Comment: @JonCrowell just checked and the import is correct. You must have something wrong in your setup.

Comment: Did you add `from __future__ import absolute_import` do your settings file? If not python will try to import schedules from your celery.py file.

Comment: Straight from celery doc """You can also start embed beat inside the worker by enabling workers -B option, this is convenient if you will never run more than one worker node, but it’s not commonly used and for that reason is NOT RECOMMENDED for production use:

$ celery -A proj worker -B"""

Comment: @asksol if you are out there, please add `from __future__ import absolute_import` to the example @ http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: Note - now this needs to be called CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE (recent versions)

Answer (score 23):

You can use django-celery application: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery

**Installation**:

```
pip install django-celery
```

To enable django-celery for your project you need to add djcelery to INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ("djcelery", )
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
```

then add the following lines to your settings.py:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

**USAGE**

On linux you can run worker with celery-beat like this:

```
python manage.py celeryd worker --loglevel=DEBUG  -E -B -c 1
python manage.py help celeryd #to find out the args meaning
```

Also you will like to monitor tasks in django admin. To enable monitoring fiture you'll need to run celerycam:

```
python /var/www/gorod/manage.py celerycam
```

To make periodic task you can use celery.decorators.periodic_task.

```
# myapp/tasks.py
import datetime
import celery

@celery.decorators.periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))
def myfunc():
    print 'periodic_task'
```

Or use

```
# settings.py
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}
```

Comment: The `@periodic_task` decorator is deprecated in Celery 3.1. https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1764