# Django 1.6.5 with Celery 3.1 for Periodic Tasks

Tags: python, django

I'm new with Django 1.6.5, and I have just completed the Poll tutorial:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

My objective is to:

1. Setup periodic tasks so it fetches data from a Oracle Server, and copy their data to my SQLite database. (Per hour basis)
2. After copying the data, I should organize the data into my own format in the SQLite database.

Currently my folder contents are:

```
/Dashboard_Web
    /Dashboard_Web
        /settings.py
        /url.py
        /wsgi.py
        /__init___.py
    /WebApp
        /admin.py
        /models.py
        /tasks.py
        /tests.py
        /view.py
        /__init__.py
    /db.sqlite3
    /manage.py
```

There's currently not much except the models.py: Data from the oracle server will be copied to mapt, datt, and sett. I will then fit the data into the new table, called data_parsed, which is the combination of mapt, datt, and sett.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class mapt(models.Model):
    s = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class datt(models.Model):
    s = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    setid = models.IntegerField()
    var = models.IntegerField()
    val = models.IntegerField()

class sett(models.Model):
    setid = models.IntegerField()
    block = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.IntegerField()
    ts = models.IntegerField()

class data_parsed(models.Model):
    setid = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    block = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    time = models.IntegerField()
```

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116573/in-celery-3-1-making-django-periodic-task) about django + periodic tasks

My question is: celery -A proj worker -B -l info command, where my question is, if I put my django project to a production server (Gunicorn, apache), does the celery worker get executed automatically?

==================================EDIT==================================

Sorry if I didn't say this earlier, I'm using Windows , and I cannot use a Ubuntu (I'd love to), since the corporate IT doesn't support it (I can install Ubuntu on a VMware, but it wouldn't have internet access.

Currently I followed celery's [tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django), and I did these steps:

1. Installed and downloaded Erlang and RabbitMQ on my Windows Machine
2. Created 3 files: celery.py, tasks.py, ____init____.py

Hence the current folder format look like:

```
/Dashboard_Web
    /Dashboard_Web
        /settings.py
        /url.py
        /wsgi.py
        /__init___.py <== Updated
        /celery.py <=== Added
    /WebApp
        /admin.py
        /models.py
        /tasks.py
        /tests.py
        /view.py
        /__init__.py
        /tasks.py <=== Added
    /db.sqlite3
    /manage.py
```

Contents of Celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Dashboard_Web.settings')

app = Celery('Dashboard_Web')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Contents of ____init____.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

Contents of tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@shared_task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y


@shared_task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)

@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(hour="*", minute="*", day_of_week="*")))
def scraper_example():
    print("Hello World")
    logger.info("Start task")
    logger.info("Task finished: result")
```

I am able to execute:

```
python manage.py runserver
celery -A Dashboard_Web worker -l INFO
```

without any problems, however, there is nothing shown in the console:

```
[2014-07-02 11:46:12,835: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2014-07-02 11:46:12,880: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2014-07-02 11:46:13,957: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:236: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, nev
er use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2014-07-02 11:46:13,994: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:236: UserWarning: U
sing settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2014-07-02 11:46:14,012: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@LEIMAX1 ready.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the steps for supervisor

```
>> apt-get install supervisor
>> service supervisor restart
```

Then create a conf file in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf` that contains something similar to:

```
[program:celery-worker]
command=/root/.virtualenvs/test/bin/celery -A Dashboard_Web worker -l INFO
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/long.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/long.out.log

[program:celery-beat]
command=/root/.virtualenvs/test/bin/celery -A Dashboard_Web beat -l INFO
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/long.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/long.out.log
```

You should also set up `celery.py` using this [tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django).

Then run:

```
>> supervisorctl reread
>> supervisorctl update
```

See the status by running

```
>> supervisorctl status
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've edited my post, unfortunately, I'm not using ubuntu

Comment: Try running `celery -A Dashboard_Web worker -l INFO` in one tab and `celery -A Dashboard_Web beat -l INFO` in another. Beat mode is what queues up tasks to be run where the worker consumes them. I also came across this link http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/07/04/django-on-windows-run-celery-as-a-windows-service/

Comment: This works! I'm not familiar with Celery, and I'm trying to get this simple example working. Then it seems like worker and beat have to exists the same time. Is there a windows version for supervising? Can celery worker and beat start automatically when I also runserver?

Comment: Actually ignore my comment, it seems that the blog contains the answers to my comment. Thanks for your help!