# how to make scheduling in django using djcelery

Tags: django-models, django-admin, django-views, djcelery

How can I make scheduling in django using djcelery with redis.How can i add starttime and endtime using this?What is the difference between crontab and interval? Can I make scheduling using djcelery?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague but is maybe related to this other [In celery 3.1, making django periodic task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116573/in-celery-3-1-making-django-periodic-task)

Comment: I want to start and stop the poll. for that where i should  write the code? How the model and celery relating?