# what is the best way for heavy periodic tasks (django)

Tags: django, celery, supervisord

i have a django app that has more than 500 tables each table is for a device (each device sends 500 data every day and i store them in database).

i should get 10 minutes,hourly,daily,weekly, monthly averages and store them in another table called averages.

i don't know what is the best way for these periodic tasks. using django modules like celery-beat or using supervisor of the host?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In celery 3.1, making django periodic task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116573/in-celery-3-1-making-django-periodic-task)

Comment: no , i know how to use celery but i was looking for fastest and best way possbile